# Use string to get attribute value python

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have this :

```
class A:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == 'a'
             return 'this'
        else:
             return 'that'
```

I would like to create another class that use 'class A' and use a string as the future attributes of 'A' like this:

```
class B:
    def use_a(self, attributes='a'):
         a = A().attributes
         return a
```

I would like that the method `use_a(class B)` return 'this' if i set attributes to 'a',
but it doesn't work and returns 'that'. But i try to do a gettattr it doesn't work either. How can I do that ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: can you make the program more clearer and explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__getattr__` is called if `A().a` doesn't exist. You still need to use `getattr` if the attribute itself is a variable.

```
def use_a(self, attribute='a'):
    a = getattr(A(), attribute)
    return a
```

Comment: `a` is an attribute, `attribute` is not. `attribute` is a variable whose *value* is the name of an attribute.

Comment: That is, `A().x` is equivalent to `getattr(A(), 'x')`, not `getattr(A(), x)`.